# How to upload the image to amazon bucket in swift3?

Tags: ios, node.js, swift3

I want to post the customer signature image to amazon s3 bucket_type server with an api...I am referring with different tutorials...I didn't get enough information from any of tutorials...I am trying with following code but I am getting nil result...

```
    funcUpload(service:String,imagedata:Data,completion:@escaping (_ result:NSDictionary?,_ error:AnyObject?) -> ()){           
 let boundaryConstant  = "----------V2y2HFg03eptjbaKO0j1"
     let urlpath:String = "http:myurl" + service        
    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string:urlpath)!
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "P0ST"
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData

    request.httpShouldHandleCookies = false
    let contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundaryConstant)"        
    request.setValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type"
    let body = NSMutableData()
     if imagedata != nil{
        body.append("--\(boundaryConstant)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)           
        body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data;   name=\"\("universalapparealproduct")\" ; filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        body.append("Content-Type: \("universalapparealproduct")\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        body.append(imagedata)
        body.append("\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)         
        }
        body.append("--\(boundaryConstant)--\r\n".data(using:      String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        request.httpBody  = body as Data       
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.ephemeral
        self.session = URLSession(configuration: config)
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {     (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if let receivedData = data
       {                      
        do
       {let resultDic = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:   receivedData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
           completion(resultDic!,nil)
        }
        catch let error
        {
            NSLog("\(error)")
        }
    }
    else if let errorMessage = error
    {
        completion(nil,errorMessage as AnyObject?)
    }
            self.session.invalidateAndCancel()
    }           
    task.resume()
    }
}
```

Please can any one help me to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

func imageUpload(service:String,token:String,imagedata:Data,completion:@escaping (_ result:NSDictionary?,_ error:AnyObject?) -> ())

```
{


    let boundaryConstant  = "----------V2y2HFg03eptjbaKO0j1"



    let params = NSMutableDictionary()
```

let bucket_name = "userspecifiedbucketname"

params.setObject("(bucket_name)", forKey:"bucket_type" as NSCopying)

```
    let urlpath:String = "http://\(myurladdress)/" + service

    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string:urlpath)!
    print("URL:\(url)")

    var request = URLRequest(url: url as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData


    let contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundaryConstant)"

    request.setValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    if token != ""
    {
        request.setValue("\(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    }
    let body = NSMutableData()
    for param in params {

        body.append("--\(boundaryConstant)\r\n" .data(using: String.Encoding.utf8,allowLossyConversion: false)! )
        body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(param.key)\"\r\n\r\n" .data(using: String.Encoding.utf8,allowLossyConversion: false)!)
        body.append("\(param.value)\r\n" .data(using: String.Encoding.utf8,allowLossyConversion: false)!)

    }
    body.append("--\(boundaryConstant)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8,allowLossyConversion: false)!)


    body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data;   name=\"\("file")\" ;  filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8,allowLossyConversion: false)!)


    body.append("Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8,allowLossyConversion: false)!)


    body.append(imagedata)

        body.append("\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8,allowLossyConversion: false)!)

        // image end



        body.append("--\(boundaryConstant)--\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8,allowLossyConversion: false)!)
        request.httpBody  = body as Data
    let postLength = "\(body.length)"
    request.setValue(postLength, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")  

}
```

NOTE: (Here bucket_name should be same as server side bucket_name )

Comment: It works for me

Answer (score 0):

1. `let urlpath:String = "http:myurl" + service`  looks like a typo.
2. I assume that the service variable contain a url with pre-signed credentials that you can upload to.  Make sure that is correct.  If not you have to have a server serve you pre-signed credentials.
3. use `PUT` not `POST`
4. I would expect that the body of the request would just be the imageData, but you seem to be adding a lot of stuff to body.  I don't know what kind of file you want to upload but you are making a weird file.  If that is your intent is fine, but just we aware that is what you are doing. If indenting to upload a custom file type, I would move all of that code to a different function  and then have another function that just uploads the data.
5. the only HTTPHeader field that you have to set is `Content-Length`.  It must be set to the size of the body that you send.
6. The expected result of the request is data with a length of 0 and no error.  So your JSONSerialization in the response block in wrong.

Comment: hi..my url i am using my app url with service as file/upoad and in back end they are using "POST" method only

Comment: body of the request is selected image and bucket_type = "my project type" so am not understanding where i have to set this bucket_type in the requested body

Comment: A common way to upload images to S3 is to get a presigned url from your backend server.  This url already contains the bucket and fileName and all the permissions you need to upload. Using this url you can directly upload to s3 without the need to go through your backend see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html. If that is what you are using then you should follow the instructions I gave.  If you are uploading the image to your server which is in turn uploads it to s3 then I can't help you because I don't know what that server expects to receive.